# Manga where a student, left behind when his class is summoned to another world, gains powers and fights monsters

Tags: story-identification, magic, isekai

It's a manga where a guy that always sleeps. He is in his classroom and his class gets summoned to another world. Since he is not in the magic circle, he gets left behind.

He still gets skills and he lives with those skills. One day monsters start to come to earth and he kills them, while an angel comes down and tries to bring him to that world.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This sounds like *My Entire Class Was Summoned to Another World except for Me (Class ga Isekai Shoukan sareta Naka Ore dake Nokotta n desu ga,* 2017).  At least it sounds like the description given in this [answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/213964/101936).

The main character is left out of the summoning circle because he was sleeping in a corner seat of the class room. He stays on earth with new powers, and it mentions that monsters from another world appear at the school.

Comment: Definitely the correct one.