A manga where all the classmate of the mc got summoned to another world instead of him but he got powers too in his earth
Chapter one show all of his classmate getting summoned and he didn't, but he got abilities too just in his world.
He then fights a dragon and an angel too i think.
He has a sister

His world has dragons and angels?

Are you thinking of Class ga Isekai Shoukan sareta Naka Ore dake Nokotta n desu ga?

A god of a different world had abruptly appeared in Kamiya Yato's classroom and forcibly summoned the entire class to his world... except for him—because he was sleeping in a seat in the corner of the class, and the summoning magic circle didn't reach him—and he ended up staying here on Earth, but with brand-new skills.
After he made it through a whole year full of police interviews and journalism reports, he finally became a high school student, but the quiet days he had hoped for were far from over—be it terrorists who decide to occupy his school or even monsters from different world, one by one new incidents take place in the town he lives in...
Will a boy without any motivation be able to save the world?



If so, it would be a dupe of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/213931/isekai-manga-where-the-main-character-is-left-in-his-original-world-and-his-clas. https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/234664/23243 mentions the angel.
